# StringContent - mediaType Parameter

Tags: c#, httpclient

Does anyone have any idea what the 'mediaType' parameter does for the `StringContent`'s constructor? Nothing is listed on its MSDN page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wow, yeah the [msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor) for that class needs some work.

When you create a new instance of `StringContent`, it always sets a media type. If you don't specify one, it uses "text/plain"; otherwise, it uses whatever you passed in. (There appears to be some validation done on the value you pass in, but I don't really understand what it's doing.)

That media type value is then used to instantiate a new `MediaTypeHeaderValue`, which is assigned to your StringContent's `Headers.ContentType` property.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers) for Headers:

> Gets the HTTP content headers as defined in RFC 2616.

The comment on the Content-Type property:

> The value of the Content-Type content header on an HTTP response.

So all that to say, it's apparently specifying the HTTP content type.

Here's a [full list of types](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/), which is too long to include here. I'm sure there's a list somewhere on MSDN too but I couldn't find one.

Comment: AKA: MIME Type. M$ really hates convention sometimes.

Comment: is "application/json" added recently? because that long list doesn't include the only content type we use throughout our project, namely "application/json".