# Forge Api PATCH request returns 415 "unsupported media type"

Tags: c#, asp.net, autodesk-forge

I am using the Forge API.
I need to execute PATCH request.
When I send it using Postman everything is fine, but when I build request using HttpRequestMessage I get a response - "415 unsupported media type".
By API documentation Content-Type I set to "application/vnd.api+json".

Body of request in Postman

[image]
[Headers of request in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E7QJ.png)

[request object structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ezjd.png)

```
JObject jsonApi = new JObject();
            jsonApi.Add("version", "1.0");
            JObject attributes = new JObject();
            attributes.Add("displayName", file.FileName);
            JObject data = new JObject();
            data.Add("type", "items");
            data.Add("id", file.ExternalFileId);
            data.Add("attributes", attributes);

            JObject request = new JObject();
            request.Add("jsonapi", jsonApi);
            request.Add("data", data);

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpRequestMessage http = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                    Method = new HttpMethod("PATCH"),
                    Headers =
                    {
                        { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer " + userLastAccessToken },
                        { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/vnd.api+json" }
                    }
                };  
                http.Content = new StringContent(request.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.api+json");
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(http);
            }
```

Comment: Instead of setting the `HttpRequestHeader.Accept` you should set `HttpRequestHeader.ContentType` to `application/vnd.api+json`

Comment: I set ContentType in http.Content = new StringContent(...), because ContentType is the attribute of body headers, not the request

Comment: ContentType specifies the data type of the data you are sending inside request body. So if you are sending json data inside request body, content type should be set. In your screenshot, I noticed you have selected `raw -> text` so content type should be set to application/text if it is working in postman

Comment: No, in Postman i set Content-Type to  "application/vnd.api+json"(see edited question above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try again with `"application/json"` or use `HttpHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation` (`"application/vnd.api+json"` might not sit well with the internal validation of `HttpHeaders`):

```
http.Content = new StringContent(request.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Or:

```
http.Content = new StringContent(request.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
http.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
```

Comment: I cannot use "application/json", because forge API strictly says that it must be  "application/vnd.api+json".
The second approach is incorect, because ContentType is the attribute of body headers, not the request
http.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");

Comment: There is no such thing as the `body headers`... you are setting the request headers anyways... the third argument passed to the `HttpContent` (or the exact implementation `StringContent`) sets the content type in your request header to a media type specified... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577173/stringcontent-mediatype-parameter) for a good explanation.

Comment: Maybe I wrote wrong, but I mean that the query object doesn't contain "Content-Type" in the header, it is located in request.Content.Headers.Content-Type(see edited question)

Comment: For sure the query object has nothing to do with media type or the error you are getting. Both of my approaches were to set the `Content-Type` of the request header, not the query object... When you created the `StringContent` the third argument sets the `Content-Type` field in the `request header` as well and not the request payload/body or query object.

Comment: This `HttpContent` approach might be confusing as you are apparently operating solely on the content/body payload rather the request headers with it but with that third argument you are indeed setting the request header and hence my second approach to suppress the internal validation of `HttpContent`(superclass of `StringContent`) and in turn `HttpHeaders` that could have rejected `application/vnd.api+json` as a valid media type...

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it helped me to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem by setting ContentType in this way

```
http.Content = new StringContent(request.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
http.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.api+json");
```

Comment: How is it different from setting `HttpRequestHeader.ContentType` to `application/vnd.api+json`?

Comment: Content-Type is a header which must be added to http.Content.Headers, not to HttpRequestMessage.Headers

Comment: HttpRequestMessage represents the request which contains its Url, body and headers. So in your code `Headers =
                    {
                        { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer " + userLastAccessToken },
                        { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/vnd.api+json" }
                    }` if you set ContentType header that will also work.

Comment: This doesn`t work, Content-Type must be set to http.Content.Headers.ContentType.
I have tried all the options and only the above works.